# WooCommerce Checkout not working on localhost

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, localhost

I just inherited a WordPress WooCommerce site and was making a local version of it. Everything works ok except for the /checkout page. I get the error

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.dev3.local refused to connect

I'm not really sure where to begin with this. Any ideas?

Comment: The live version doesn't have this problem...

Comment: check under woocommerce->settings->checkout->force secure checkout - it might be that that option is enabled -@Peter Breen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a great deal of caution: don't forget that a local site can still communicate with payment gateways.

With that in mind there's a good chance the issue is down to your checkout security settings. WooCommerce will force HTTPS on checkouts which won't work on your local server unless you've configured it in the right way.

Option 1: Go to WooCommerce -> Settings -> Checkout and uncheck "Force secure checkout". 
Option 2: Configure SSL on your local server with a self-signed cert.

Comment: Perfect, option 1 worked like a charm. I'll be careful with it though.

Comment: Adding to the above answer, on newer versions: The checkbox can now be found in: WooCommerce -> Settings -> Advanced